# Tooltip on PrimeNG tree node icon

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I have a requirement to add tooltip to PrimeNG Tree node icon. Could you please suggest me if there is a way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: If you post the code we might be

Comment: Hi, PrimeNG TreeNode has different properties like label, children, leaf, icon, etc.... I can provide the icon property a value (fontawesome icon name) and the tree node shows that icon but there is no feature available to show tololtip for that icon. Please refer "http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree" for details about tree and you can find sample code as well

Comment: It is not for us to search, read and parse code samples, that is the work you put it in, we help with a solution based on that code sample. Show the code based on both script/template as well as the rendered result, so our suggestions will be as accurate as possible. **Do note**, code should be within the question, not linked.

Comment: Have you used PrimeNG Tree node and understand the question? It is of no use ask for code that obviously is not available. It is not a trivial question and there is not a lot to search about, out there.

Answer (score 4):

to achieve what you are trying to do you need to use a template inside your primeng tree like here:

```
<p-tree #tree [value]="assembliesTree"
    selectionMode="single"
    [pTooltip]="desiredTooltip"
    (mouseover)="nodeTooltipOver($event)"
    (mouseout)="nodeTooltipOut($event)"
    [(selection)]="..."
    (onNodeSelect)="..."
    (onNodeExpand)="..."
<template let-node pTemplate type="default">
    <span pTooltip="{{ desiredTooltip }}">{{ node.label }}</span>
</template>
```

You need to import the primeNG tooltip component so you can use it in (span inside the template). The tooltip inside the span will read the content of the string variable desiredTooltip, so you need to declare it in your component:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class ThreedViewerComponent implements AfterViewInit {

private desiredTooltip: string;

...
```

Then write the functions that modified the variable when the mouse enter or leave a node:

```
nodeTooltipOver(parameter) {
    if (parameter) {
        this.desiredTooltip = 'your tooltip';
    }
}
```

on mouseout you might want to clear the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **title** attribute(inside Angular element < ng-template >...</ ng-template >) as an alternative for the PrimeNG Tree node tooltip.

**HTML**

```
<p-tree [value]="tree"
   selectionMode="..."
   [(selection)]="...">
   <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
       <span title={{node.label}}>{{node.label}}</span>
   </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by template inside the p-tree element

**HTML**

```
   <p-tree 
    [value]="valuesList" 
    (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect($event)" 
    (onNodeUnselect)="nodeUnselect($event)">
    <ng-template let-node  pTemplate="default">
       <span> {{ node.label}}
       <i class="pi pi-exclamation-circle" pTooltip="This is tooltip"   tooltipPosition="top">
       </i>
       </span>
    </ng-template>
    </p-tree>
```